# "gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname" while sending email from Azure databricks python notebook

Tags: python, azure, smtp, databricks, smtplib

I am trying to send a mail from my Azure databricks notebook via my company SMTP server.
I am able to run the same script on my local machine. And the mail is being sent when running the script from local.

But, when I am running the script from databricks, I am getting the error *No address associated with hostname*

The script -

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

server = smtplib.SMTP("COMPANY SMTP SERVER", COMPANY_SMTP_PORT)
fromaddr = "username@companyname.com"
toaddr = "username@companyname.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Email test"
body = "test mail"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
```

Error traceback -

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2889814627634467> in <module>
      3 from email.mime.text import MIMEText
      4 
----> 5 server = smtplib.SMTP("COMPANY SMTP SERVER", COMPANY_SMTP_PORT)
      6 fromaddr = "username@companyname.com"
      7 toaddr = "username@companyname.com"

/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    253 
    254         if host:
--> 255             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    256             if code != 220:
    257                 self.close()

/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py in connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    337             port = self.default_port
    338         sys.audit("smtplib.connect", self, host, port)
--> 339         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    340         self.file = None
```

Can anyone provide some insights as to what might be the issue, and how could I rectify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve by using gmail smtp server to send mails.

Databricks is an external environment to my company's outlook mail server, so white-listing was required for sending mails through company smtp server.